# error when trying to install "npm node-sass --save-dev"

Tags: node.js, npm, cmd

[Please Help! I am trying to install npm sass package and I get this error 'gyp err'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b6G3.png)

Comment: Based on the error, you need to install `python` first before you can use `node-sass`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well, have you tried reading the docs as suggested in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

The error in the image is related to `node-gyp` instead of `node-sass`, and to install `node-gyp` we need to install python firstly.

see [this ref](http://adilapapaya.com/docs/node-gyp/).

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe it's te version of the nodeJs package.**

I downloaded the Latest Features and it didn't work for me. For that reason I downloaded the Recommended For most Users and that's it. I installed the `node-sass --save-dev` without problems.